# Rails landing pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, controllers

I've decided to put a landing page on my website [goldhat.org](http://goldhat.org). I want users to be able to go directly to this page if they are logged in and be directed to a landing page if they aren't logged in. The landing page is currently sitting [here](http://goldhat.org/welcome). If one clicks on the "browse website" link at the top, it will go to what is currently the home page.

Basically I want the landing page and what is currently the home page to share the "www.goldhat.org" web address. I can see how this is easy enough to do with a logged in? conditional, but what about someone who isn't logged in and browses the site. I only really want the landing page to be displayed once.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a session variable to keep track of whether a visitor that is not logged in has viewed the landing page or not.  Something along the lines of:

```
def index
  if !logged_in? && !session[:visited_welcome_page]
    redirect_to welcome_path
  else
    # Render the main view of goldhat.org
  end
end

def welcome
  session[:visited_welcome_page] = true
  # Render welcome view
end
```

Comment: Sounds great! Will give it a go.

Comment: I suggest doing the logged_in? thing on your Application controller with a before_filter. Otherwise you will repeat yourself a lot.